# Code with triggered if statement is ignored

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

This is the code where an Image UI's sprite image is switched depending on key(s) pressed down:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ImageController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Sprite left;
    public Sprite topleft;
    public Sprite backleft;
    public Sprite right;
    public Sprite topright;
    public Sprite backright;
    public Sprite top;
    public Sprite back;
    public Sprite nothing;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                Debug.Log("HI");                          // Not ignored??
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topleft;   // Ignored
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topright;
            }
            else
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = top;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = backleft;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = backright;
            }
            else
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().sprite = back;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code within the first nested if statement (in this case, `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {}`) will not work (the image will not change). I have added `Debug.Log("HI")` in both if statements to see if it works and it does. Changing the conditions also does not work. All other nested if statements work properly though. Also note that the images are correctly placed within the Unity editor.

So why is the line `GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topleft;` being completely ignored though the `if` statements' conditions are all met?

Comment: Please explain why you are nesting that `if` statement that reads from the keyboard. That's not a good idea.

Comment: Note: I did not put this in Game Development Stack Exchange as the problem is entirely based on code rather than the game itself

Comment: @Programmer It's to make sure both keys are currently being held down. Having them separate will make the program assume that only one of the two keys are being held down and thus display the wrong image.

Comment: Both keys? You mean the up and the left arrow keys?

Comment: @Programmer Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150488/discussion-between-anthony-pham-and-programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topleft;   // Ignored
```

It's not being ignored. The value is assigned as expected, but it is later overwritten by `top` since you have an `else` that is **always** executed for `LeftArrow`.

```
        // Assign as the default value first.
        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = top;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topleft; 
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = topright;
        }
```